# Application deployed on server won't work as on local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application which I developed using c# and asp.net mvc (MVC5). I used the publishing tool of visual studio 2017 to publish a release package of the app which I could deploy on a server.
The app principally has two functionalities, one to register students and another to register their notes.
The one to register students works fine and I can do everything related to that (editing, deleting, etc...)
When I try to register a note for a particular student, I get an error. No matter what I do, I can't register notes.
I got an "Error.cshtml" view in my app and it's that view which is returned to me every time I try registering a note for a student.
The most strange issue is that on my local machine everything works fine (I can register both students and their notes). But once I deploy the same working version on the server, the notes functionnality does not.
Below are some portions of code:

Create View :

```
    <div class="form-group" id="id1">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NotePremierTrimestre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NotePremierTrimestre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "id01" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NotePremierTrimestre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Resultats controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save([Bind(Include = "IdResultat,NotePremierTrimestre,NoteDeuxiemeTrimestre,NoteTroixiemeTrimestre,NotePremierSemestre,NoteDeuxiemeSemestre,MoyenneGenerale,Mention,MoyenneCEPE,MoyenneFSLC,MoyenneBEPC,MoyenneCAP,MoyenneGCEO,MoyenneProbatoire,MoyenneBACC,MoyenneGCEA,MoyenneBTS,MoyenneDUT,MoyenneHND,MoyLicence,MoyMasterPro,MoyMasterRecherche,IdApprennant,IdAnnee")] Resultat resultat, [Bind(Include = "IdNoteDiscipline,Note,IdDiscipline,IdResultat")] NoteDiscipline noteDiscipline, string examenOfficiel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (resultat.NotePremierTrimestre != null & resultat.NoteDeuxiemeTrimestre != null & resultat.NoteTroixiemeTrimestre != null)
            {
                resultat.MoyenneGenerale = (resultat.NotePremierTrimestre + resultat.NoteDeuxiemeTrimestre + resultat.NoteTroixiemeTrimestre) / 3;
            }
            else if (resultat.NotePremierSemestre != null & resultat.NoteDeuxiemeSemestre != null)
            {
                resultat.MoyenneGenerale = (resultat.NotePremierSemestre + resultat.NoteDeuxiemeSemestre) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                resultat.MoyenneGenerale = 0;
            }

            if (examenOfficiel == "BEPC")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneBEPC = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "CAP")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneCAP = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "GCE O'Level")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneGCEO = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "Probatoire")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneProbatoire = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "Baccalauréat")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneBACC = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "GCE A'Level")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneGCEA = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "BTS")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneBTS = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "Licence")
            {
                resultat.MoyLicence = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "Master Professionnel")
            {
                resultat.MoyMasterPro = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "Master Recherche")
            {
                resultat.MoyMasterRecherche = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else if (examenOfficiel == "HND")
            {
                resultat.MoyenneHND = resultat.MoyenneCEPE;
            }
            else
            {

            }

            //Vérification de la base de données pour voir si un apprenant avec cette note a déjà été enregistré
            //Resultat result2 = null;
            //try
            //{
            //    result2 = db.Resultats.Where(b => b.IdApprennant == resultat.IdApprennant && b.IdAnnee == resultat.IdAnnee).First();
            //} catch
            //{

            //}
            //if (result2 == null)
            //{
            db.Resultats.Add(resultat);

            db.SaveChanges();
            int id = resultat.IdResultat;
            noteDiscipline.IdResultat = id;

            db.NoteDisciplines.Add(noteDiscipline);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //}
        }

        ViewBag.IdAnnee = new SelectList(db.AnneeAcademiques, "IdAnnee", "Intitule", resultat.IdAnnee);
        ViewBag.IdApprennant = new SelectList(db.Apprenants, "IdApprenant", "Code", resultat.IdApprennant);
        //return View("Error");

        return View(resultat);
    }
```

With the above code I expect to send some marks from the view to the controller and to be redirected to an "Index" view or else to the same "Create" view. This works fine on my machine and I have this same code on the server, but once I type some marks and hit the register button, I have the "Error" view which is thrown back.
The other strange thing is that the line of code which returns the "Error" View has been commented, but it still shows up in the server.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What issue are you facing?. Also please share your code

Comment: You are asking in the right place but not in the best shape. If you see the Error.cshtml page it means that at some point your code is throwing an unhandled exception. You will have to post the code that runs when you face the error page (see the guideline for creating a [mcve]) so we can help you

Comment: It sounds like the connection string to the database is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hosted your package to IIS server, go to basic setting of your application and change the physical path to source code instead of build package. Then run your application from IIS and keep debugger in your application in visual studio. This way you will be able to find out what could be the issue while running the app from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to configure IIS for ASP.Net Application. Just Select all asp.net options when install IIS on your server.
Follow the this installation process. I am sure you will get your solution and the application run in server as local machine.
https://www.logisofteducation.com/2018/08/how-to-install-iis-server.html

[How to install iis server?](https://www.logisofteducation.com/2018/08/how-to-install-iis-server.html)

Comment: Thanks @Dutta for your response, but actually on that same server there are a good number of asp.net apps running, so IIS has already been installed and the asp.net option configured to work. My app is the only one to have a problem